# Unable to compile with vbnc on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mono, c#

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. In order to try out some .NET exercises, I installed the below mono packages:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime mono-mcs mono-vbnc
```

Now, I've got the mono csharp compiler (mcs) working fine. However, the VB.NET compiler (vbnc) is throwing the below error:

The library 'System.Design.dll' could not be found

Any idea what have I missed ?

Comment: @TheLordofTime - Then why do we have Mono packages on Ubuntu 12.04? And why we have mono programs like tomboy and banshee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vbnc will by default add many references, and apparently some of those are not installed by default on Ubuntu.

I do not know what you have to install to get System.Design.dll, but you can disable the default references by passing -noconfig:

```
vbnc -noconfig test.vb
```

Note that this will also disable a few other default features, most notably all the default imports will be disabled too.

So for instance this code:

```
Class Test
    Shared Sub Main
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World")
    End Sub
End Class
```

when compiled like this:

```
vbnc -noconfig test.vb
```

will fail with:

```
test.vb (3,21) : error VBNC30451: 'Console' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

The fix is easy, just pass -imports: to vbnc

```
vbnc -noconfig test.vb -imports:System
```

and now it should compile just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rolf, unfortunately your solution doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS:

```
$ vbnc -noconfig test.vb -imports:System
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

Error VBNC30456: 'ComponentModel' is not a member of 'Global.System'.
Error VBNC30456: 'CodeDom' is not a member of 'Global.System'.
Error VBNC30456: 'ComponentModel' is not a member of 'Global.System'.
Error VBNC30456: 'CodeDom' is not a member of 'Global.System'.
Error VBNC30456: 'CodeDom' is not a member of 'Global.System'.
There were 5 errors and 0 warnings.
```

Actually, you should use **vbnc2** to compile your code, like this:

```
$ vbnc2 test.vb
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

Assembly 'test, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' saved successfully to 'test.exe'.
Compilation successful
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same issue the next way:

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-system-design4.0-cil
```